# Async thunk doesn't get executed when running trough test files

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I am currently working on a migration, removing react context and using reduxt toolkit.
Basically created the basics for it:

- slices for state management
- thunks to handle the API

Everything worked fine on the app, with the exception of the jest tests for async thunks, I added some console logs and the async thunk never get called.

Here is my code (**jest test)**:

```
import { AsyncThunkAction, configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";
import shared from "../../config/shared";
import global from "../slices/globalSlice";
jest.mock('axios');
const getConfiguredStore = () =>
  configureStore({
    reducer: {
      global,
    },
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
      getDefaultMiddleware({
        serializableCheck: false,
      }),
  });
describe("test1", () => {    
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  it("test1.1", async () => {
    const store = getConfiguredStore()
    const mockRequest = {
        globalId: 'asdas'
      };
      const postSpy = jest.spyOn(axios, 'post').mockResolvedValueOnce({ data: { globalId: '1' } });
      const res = store.dispatch(getGlobalInfo(mockRequest.globalId)).unwrap();
      console.log('RESSSS2: ', res)
      expect(postSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

**Async thunk file**

```
export const getGlobalInfo = createAsyncThunk(
  "feature/getGlobalInfo",
  async (globalId: string, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get<IGlobalInfoResponse[]>(
        `globalInfo/api`,
        {
          timeout: QUERY_TIMEOUT,
        }
      );
      return response;
    } catch (error) {
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(apiErr);
    }
  }
);
```

If I try to put a log at the beginning of the async thunk it never reached there when I run the test. It feels like I am missing some configuration or I am missing something in how to do this test.

Appreciate any help!

Thanks!